# How to enable response paging for a WFS-service request with st_read in R

Tags: r, paging, r-sf

WFS 2.0.0 services may implement request paging. If so, it is my understanding that with GDAL using the parameter `PagingAllowed=ON` you can enable request paging. Is there a similar parameter for the `st_read` function in the `sf` package in R? It would be very handy!
For now, if the number of hits for a query is higher than the server limit, I have to split op the request myself. It would be nice if `st_read` would take care of this for me. I recently discovered that it does so automagically for requests to ESRI hosted feature services, because GDAL supports request paging for these kind of services. So maybe also for WFS services?

===== edit =====

This gist contains some example requests to WFS and ESRI hosted feature services to illustrate my question: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/FrieseWoudloper/bb71ebe402a486530c9a809cb6cbaacc/raw/459e318018a23b75b3ab9b93bb247239a4965ee7/StackOverflow.html

Comment: Can you point us to a WFS server we can test on?

Comment: @Spacedman I created a gist with some examples to illustrate my question: http://htmlpreview.github.com/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/FrieseWoudloper/bb71ebe402a486530c9a809cb6cbaacc/raw/459e318018a23b75b3ab9b93bb247239a4965ee7/StackOverflow.html